# php stdClass Object

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I'm a bit lost.

with `print_r` I get these results

```
stdClass Object ( [distlat] => 0 [distlng] => 0 [id] => 380 )
```

but how can echo the results?

like `stdClass->distlat->$distlat` ?

please give me a hint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So,

```
echo $object->distlat;
echo $object->distlng;
```

doesn't work for you?

Comment: dunk now i wrote the same like you it thrown an error i copyed your and it works, weird, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You are using `print_r` on a variable I guess, such **$myVariable**

To access the data of your object use :

```
echo $myVariable->distlat;
echo $myVariable->distlng;
echo $myVariable->id;
```

And try using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. Information is a little completer with `var_dump`. (You have type information with it).