# Basic PHP - Getting Data Out of an stdClass Object

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quick question about something I imagine must be pretty easy - I've done a little research and found some links that seem promising, especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111481/php-stdclass-object), but it doesn't work for me for some reason.

Anyway, I made a stored procedure in MySQL and tested it with MySQL Workbench, and it works - it just adds num1 and num2 and returns the result. Now I'm trying to get it to work in PHP, but the result, instead of being an integer, is an array of one stdClass Object which contains that integer. That makes sense from the point of view of procedures that return a lot of data, but I'm having some trouble getting down to just the integer.

I run this:

```
   CALL database.routine(2,7)
```

And I save the results into $var. When I run print_r($var), I get:

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
    [num1+num2] => 9
    )
    )
```

So, to get past the Array part, I specifically asked for the first element in it, by running print_r($var[0]), which gets me:

```
    stdClass Object
    (
    [num1+num2] => 9
    )
```

And now I need to go one level deeper...I tried what the page I linked to above said and attempted to get to $var[0]->[num1+num2], as the field appears to be named, but that doesn't work. I've also tried a few combinations of single quotes and double quotes, but no luck. How do I get the number 9 out of this object?

Comment: Consider modifying your database routine to use a column alias, so instead of returning the key `num1+num2` it returns a more useful one.  `SELECT num1+num2 AS your_number`

Comment: Great idea, I didn't know I could do that!

Comment: while the other answers are technical correct, Michaels is the only good solution regarding a clean code (imho, of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
$var[0]->{'num1+num2'}
```

Comment: AHA! Now THERE's a punctuation combination I hadn't tried! Works perfectly! Thanks! I'll accept your answer once the timer goes down

Comment: [Fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) loses today

Comment: Yeah I agree, on these types of questions your going to get a ton of users pushing the same answer. Points should be awarded to the first responder really.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$var[0]->{"num1+num2"}
```

or

```
$prop = 'num1+num2';
$var[0]->$prop;
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
$var[0]->{'num1+num2'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following `$var[0]->{'num1+num2'}`

Answer (score 0):

This is crazy but it might just work!

`$var[0]->{'num1+num2'}`